# Discord.py always sends the same wrong response

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I have a problem with **Discord.py** which I really tried hard, but couldn't get the result I expected even though I thought a lot on how to fix it. I will try to include all of them.

**So let me summarize the problem.**

First of all, here is my code where I got the problem from:

```
if message.content.startswith("lerconics"):
                
            print(usr_msg)
            if usr_msg=="sa":
                msg="as"

                cmd="sa"
                cmds.append(cmd)

            if usr_msg=="merhaba":
                msg="merhaba {0.user.mention}"

                cmd="sa"
                cmds.append(cmd)
                
            if usr_msg=="lerconics":
                msg="efendim {0.user.mention}?"
                cmd="sa"
                cmds.append(cmd)
                
            if usr_msg=="yardım":
                msg="as"
     
                cmd="sa"
                cmds.append(cmd)
                
            if usr_msg == "dm":
                msg="İşte. Dm'ini kontrol etmeyi unutma. :)"
                await message.author.send(usr_arg)
                cmd="sa"
                cmds.append(cmd)
                
            if usr_msg == "":
                msg="Umm.. Why did u call me for nothing? these people... Please tell your request in the message you call me. Or else I'm so lazy. lol"
            else:
                msg=" There is no command like that! To get a list of all the available commands, use the command help!"
            
            await message.channel.send(msg)
```

It messages *There is no command like that! To get a list of all the available commands, use the command help!*  what you write as "lerconics ...."

So, I did actually think the main problem here was that the compiler bypasses all the if clauses and comes to else, but i tested with a print command in each if, and it printed. But it still gives the same result.

I even thought the problem could be with the await part below, since it does DM me.. I really don't know.

**Note:** There is no problem with variables if you think I didn't declare them. I just got the important part. If you think you need all the code, go look at the bottom of the post.

All the code:

```
#Welcome to our bot, Lerconics! (important links coming soon)

#I am a Discord bot coded with using Python 3.8 by LERCDSGN manager nicknamed Programmer Potato (I just made it up lol)!

#Enjoy our bot and if you're interested in the codes, there are notes meaning some easy steps for you to follow! Let's start, then. Remember, notes that are in a line with a code or said nfm(note for me) at the beginning, they are notes for my creator!


#--------------------------------------------------------

#---------  STEP 1: Importing Needed Modules  -----------


#Firstly, I have to Import Discord or else I cannot connect to the app.

print("Importing Discord...")

import discord

print("Succesfully Done.")

#-- STEP 2: Declaring Variables And Defining Functions --


#------     STEP 2A : Declaring Variables          ------

#This is my Token. It's like a credit card number or a password of mine so if it's stolen, my life is in danger because anyone who has this would be able to control me!

TOKEN = 'NzQzNDYxODY0MjQyOTM3OTU3.XzVA0Q.DICCboiztcEb3iFpJzcWauF8Kp8'

#This step makes it simple when making something by referencing the client!

client = discord.Client()

#------     STEP 2B : Defining Functions        ------


#Check when an event happens...

@client.event

async def on_message(message):
    MSG=""
    cmd=""
    cmds=[]
    cmd_num=1
    usr_arg="Please enter an argument for me to apply the command on, like a message to send!"
    chn = message.channel
    usr_msg=message.content[10:]
    if ":" in usr_msg:
        usr_arg=usr_msg[usr_msg.find(":")+1:]
        usr_msg=usr_msg[:usr_msg.find(":")]
        
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    else:
    
    #Sadly and happily, I won't be able to reply myself to prevent a possible loop!
        if message.content.startswith("lerconics"):
                
            print(usr_msg)
            if usr_msg=="sa":
                msg="as"

                cmd="sa"
                cmds.append(cmd)

            if usr_msg=="merhaba":
                msg="merhaba {0.user.mention}"

                cmd="sa"
                cmds.append(cmd)
                
            if usr_msg=="lerconics":
                msg="efendim {0.user.mention}?"
                cmd="sa"
                cmds.append(cmd)
                
            if usr_msg=="yardım":
                msg="as"
     
                cmd="sa"
                cmds.append(cmd)
                
            if usr_msg == "dm":
                msg="İşte. Dm'ini kontrol etmeyi unutma. :)"
                await message.author.send(usr_arg)
                cmd="sa"
                cmds.append(cmd)
                
            if usr_msg == "":
                msg="Umm.. Why did u call me for nothing? these people... Please tell your request in the message you call me. Or else I'm so lazy. lol"
            else:
                msg=" There is no command like that! To get a list of all the available commands, use the command help!"
            
            await message.channel.send(msg)
    
    
    #T will check if they actually called me to not annoy others!
    
    

#when an event happens
        
@client.event

#when the code is succesfully ran

async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='lerconics help'))
    #sends name and id of the bot in the console to confirm its running with this bot
    
    print('Enter succesfull! Logged in as the user with an \n ID of ' + str(client.user.id) + "and a name of " + str(client.user.name) + ". Go check if it worked!")

    #Sends a message in the home channel (using its ID) to tell the bot's online again in Discord.

#running the token to start
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: That's not your actual code, unless you're getting a `SyntaxError`. There's a very obvious unbalanced quote. We can't be expected to guess at which errors are relevant and which are typos. Please make sure the code you share here actually reflects your problem.

Comment: What? So you mean I stole it? Oh, no.. You could tell me what could I do..

Comment: You can use single quotes inside double quotes in python without a syntax error

Comment: @Chris .........

Comment: ...no. Not that you stole it, but that it isn't actually the code you're running. Look at the syntax highlighting. It's broken because of an unbalanced quote: `if usr_msg=="help:`. Also, you'd have an `IndentationError` there even if you fix the quote. If you're sharing code that's different from what you're running, we can't help.

Comment: ok thanks ill try @jreiss1923

Comment: Oh wait I see the unbalanced quote you're totally right @Chris

On line 6 you have to add a quotation mark to the end of your line

Comment: oh, ok. i think u r right there @Chris oh no it didnt work :(

Comment: but it doesn't work anyways @jreiss1923 it was actually not mainly english in my code i had to translate it to explain it better original code still gives the problem and idk why i dont get any errors

Comment: @LerconnDesign, please [edit] your question and fix your code. We can't help if the code you're sharing isn't accurate.

Comment: i did, thanks for your patience to my noobness btw xd

Comment: i think i gotta sleep it's 01.26 AM here. Hope it doesn't differ :)

Comment: heyyyy i figured it outtt! It was just a basic problem where i made all the code with "if"s, so the compiler read if, if... and  return else if the last if is not True! So i made them "elif" and BOOM! Thanks to whoever tried to help. I will call you out if there's a problem again! It looks good for now...

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space)*.

I figured it out! It was just a basic problem where I made all the code with "if"s, so the compiler read **if, if... and  return else if the last if is not True!**.

So I made them **"elif"** and BOOM! Found the solution but still not sure.